# Chrome / Safari image loader, first time opening

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, css, safari

Built my own image slider, works perfectly inside firefox. Yet in chrome / safari the images tend to not load the first time the page is opened. (if you refresh everything is fine)

```
var count = $("#show-image img").size();
var img = $("#show-image img");
$(document).ready(function () {
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
    var width = img[i].width;
    var height = img[i].height;
    $(img[i]).css({"width": width, "height": height});
    console.log(img[i].width);
}
});
```

In chrome and safari, the first time the page loads some of the images are getting the height and width set to 0px. I'm assuming cause the images aren't fully loaded yet.

How is it possible to run the code, when page is ACTUALLY fully loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick and simple solution, use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead.

A better solution would be to use [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#show-image').imagesLoaded(function() {
        /* your code here */
    });
});
```

The advantage being that you only have to wait for those specific images to be loaded, instead of *everything* as you would for `.load()`.

Comment: Weird, I've never had any issues with .load(), even on cached images. Looks like a decent plugin though.

Comment: `.load()` fixes the problem he's having, which is with `.ready()`.

Comment: The plugin worked perfectly, real easy to implement. Thanks for the link :)