# Odd div overflow in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

For some reason, only in Chrome, when you refresh this portfolio page the thumbnails break and move down into the footer.

The only way I can replicate it is by refreshing the page.

Very weird.. could it be a JS issue?

before: http://cl.ly/463x3d0y1D1k3535162C

after refresh: http://cl.ly/3Y3Q1A2u3N373s0r210s

Live site: http://atavist.baltimoredrew.com/?post_type=portfolio

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are applying a height to the article elements inside #portfolio.

My guess is the 'equal height' code you've got going is running too early before the images have loaded so your aren't getting accurate heights.

Try making sure the page is ready (images loaded, dom ready, etc..) before implementing the equal height bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This bit? `<article style="height: 199px;" id="portfolio-item-id-146" class="post-146 type-portfolio status-publish portfolio-item atavist-originals">` That's a function or something injecting that. I'll have to look for it and see where its coming from. I could be wrong, but I say that because once it breaks, it changes to 87px.

Comment: Yes.  I noticed the height was changing from reload to reload.  Look at portfolio.js around line 84.

Comment: I suspect this is the correct answer. Here's a related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669567/chrome-safari-image-loader-first-time-opening/7669602#7669602. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709557/chrome-change-style-after-refresh-and-corrects-it-when-i-right-click-to-inspect/10709790#10709790

Answer (score 0):

First thing that stood out as odd was this piece of html at the bottom? of the page:

```
<style type="text/css" class="fluid-images">img{max-width:100%;height:auto;}</style>
```

There is no class attribute for a style tag, and all of your styling should go at the top of your document.

It may also have something to do with this:

```
.fix::before, .fix::after, .col-full::before, .col-full::after {
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The above code is obviously a css hack, but I don't recognize it or its purpose.

Comment: That's a plugin.. not sure why it embeds it's CSS at the bottom of the page like that. That's weird, thanks for the catch. Never noticed it. Looking at the .fix now.

Comment: That CSS rule is obviously just a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/). Nothing to see there.

Comment: It was WP Fluid Images plugin causing the issue. I think moving it to the top isn't going to fix it though. It's a bit of a qwirky plugin and I've noticed some issues.

Comment: I thought might be a clearfix too, but i have never seen a hack like that, with double colons.